# Combine multiple row data using sum() over(Partion by) in mysql

Tags: mysql, window-functions, mysql-5.5

```
SELECT orders.Stock ,lflayouts.sides, count(*) as Quantity FROM dash_relationship 
JOIN orders ON orders.UID = dash_relationship.form_id
JOIN lfitems ON lfitems.uid = orders.UID
Join lflayouts ON lflayouts.id = lfitems.layout_id
WHERE dash_relationship.machine_id='108'
GROUP BY orders.stock,lflayouts.sides;
```

The above query outputs as follows

```
STOCK   SIDES    QUANTITY
paper1    1         214
paper1    2         210
paper2    1           7
paper3    1           2
```

Now my question is what if I want to get total of individual stocks based on different sides. So I tried using the below query and it threw me an error saying server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition) at line 1

```
SELECT orders.Stock ,lflayouts.sides, count(*) as Quantity, SUM(lflayouts.sides) OVER(partition by orders.stock) as Total FROM dash_relationship 
JOIN orders ON orders.UID = dash_relationship.form_id
JOIN lfitems ON lfitems.uid = orders.UID
Join lflayouts ON lflayouts.id = lfitems.layout_id
WHERE dash_relationship.machine_id='108'
GROUP BY orders.stock,lflayouts.sides;

EXPECTED OUTPUT
STOCK   SIDES    QUANTITY TOTAL
paper1    1         214    414 or 214
paper1    2         210    414
paper2    1           7      7
paper3    1           2      2
```

Comment: So what is your MySQL version? For running total, I think you need the [order by] after [partition by]

Comment: @GenWan MySQL 5.5.62

Comment: MySQL has supported window functions since version 8.0.

Comment: I tried using order by inside over(partition by orders.stock order by lflayouts.sides) same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.5.62 does not support window functions.

You can use standard join to achieve it but the query will look more complex.

```
SELECT    T1.Stock
         ,T1.sides
         ,Sum(T2.Quantity) as RunningTotal
FROM     (SELECT orders.Stock ,lflayouts.sides, count(*) as Quantity 
          FROM 
              dash_relationship 
              JOIN orders ON orders.UID = dash_relationship.form_id
              JOIN lfitems ON lfitems.uid = orders.UID
              JOIN lflayouts ON lflayouts.id = lfitems.layout_id
              WHERE dash_relationship.machine_id='108'
              GROUP BY orders.stock,lflayouts.sides
         ) T1
         INNER JOIN 
         (
          SELECT orders.Stock ,lflayouts.sides, count(*) as Quantity 
          FROM 
              dash_relationship 
              JOIN orders ON orders.UID = dash_relationship.form_id
              JOIN lfitems ON lfitems.uid = orders.UID
              JOIN lflayouts ON lflayouts.id = lfitems.layout_id
              WHERE dash_relationship.machine_id='108'
              GROUP BY orders.stock,lflayouts.sides
         ) T2
         ON   T1.sides >= T2.sides
         AND  T1.Stock = T2.Stock
GROUP BY  T1.Stock
         ,T1.sides
Order BY  T1.Stock
         ,T1.sides
```